# Android studio trying to connect lots of ports on local (port 5037 time_await)

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to make a client/server connection using SOCKETS.

Server side is Java in Eclipse,
Client side is in Android Studio.

There is some codes in both server and client sides for socket connection.

The connection was SUCCESSFUL yesterday.Today, I tried to connect to server with android app client, I have FAİLED.

When I check connections from **netstat -a -n** , I saw this:

(When I open the client)

[image]

That's weird because I have seen this ports before connection codes work.And the ports increases.

**And Server Codes:**

```
public class CapitalizeServer {

static  ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("The capitalization server is running.");

    int clientNumber = 0;
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(44057);
    try {
        while (true) {
            new Capitalizer(listener.accept(), clientNumber++).start();
        }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}
private static class Capitalizer extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    private int clientNumber;
    private String uname,pass;
    private boolean checked;

    public Capitalizer(Socket socket, int clientNumber) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.clientNumber = clientNumber;
        log("New connection with client# " + clientNumber + " at " + socket);
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            String input = in.readLine();
            if(input.substring(0, "uname:".length()).equals("uname:")){
                this.uname = input.substring(6);
            }else{
                return;  //Programı durdur
            }
            input = in.readLine();
            if(input.substring(0,"pass:".length()).equals("pass:")){
                this.pass = input.substring(5);
            }else{
                return; //Programı durdur
            }
            if(this.pass != null && !checked){
                if(checkPass() == 1){
                    //Yanıt olumlu olduğu için bağlantı clientlar arasına eklenir.
                    Client cc = new Client(uname, pass, socket, 0, 1);
                    clients.add(cc);
                    checked = true;
                }else{
                    //Yanıt olumuz ise bağlantı koparılır.
                    socket.close();
                    log("Socket Closed!" + socket);
                    checked = true;
                }
            }

            while (true) {
                if (input == null || input.equals(".")) {
                    break;
                }


              //Mesajlar iletilir.
                if(input.substring(0,3)=="com:"){

                    switch (input.substring(4,5)) {
                    case "1": //Attack başlat 1         şİMDİLİK SADECE BU SEÇENEK AKTİF
                        //pHp ile random person belirle. (uname döndürür.)
                        //clients arrayında olup olmadığını kontrol et.(online mı ve savaşta mı)
                        //->eğer online ise, savaşta olup olmadığına bak
                        //  eğer savaşta ise saldırılmaz.
                        //  Eğer savaşta değil ise saldır, socket ile onu da savaş alanına al
                        //->Eğer online değil ise savaşı başlat.Adama da mesaj at.

                        attack1();

                        break;
                    case "2": //Attack başlat 2

                        break;
                    case "3": //Attack başlat 3

                        break;
                    case "4": //Attack başlat 4

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log("Error handling client# " + clientNumber + ": " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Couldn't close a socket, what's going on?");
            }
            log("Connection with client# " + clientNumber + " closed");
        }
    }
    public void attack1(){
        try {
            // open a connection to the site
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/attack/attack.php");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            // activate the output
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
            // send your parameters to your site
            ps.print("firstKey=firstValue");
            ps.print("&secondKey=secondValue");

            // we have to get the input stream in order to actually send the request
            //con.getInputStream();

            // close the print stream
            ps.close();

            BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = cin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
    }
    public int checkPass(){
        //Connect to db and check the pass and uname
        //Php kodları arasında check işlemini yapan url'yi çalıştır
        //Yanıt olumlu ise 1, değilse 0 döndür.
        try {
            // open a connection to the site
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost/userControls/singin.php");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            // activate the output
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            //con.setDoInput(true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
            // send your parameters to your site
            ps.print(URLEncoder.encode("uname","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uname, "UTF-8"));
            ps.print(URLEncoder.encode("&pass=","UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "utf-8"));

            ps.close();
            System.out.println("111111");
            BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("222222");
            String line = null;
            while ((line = cin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(":::::::Geldik la Geldiiiik:::::::::   " + line);
            }
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }

        return 1;
    }
    private void log(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
}
```

**And clients first activitys code:**

```
public class SignInMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

Button button18;
EditText et1,et2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signin_menu);
    button18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button18);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

public void button18Click(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("uname",et1.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("pass",et2.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}

 }
```

I am using WAMP Server.
And there is something weird about it.I cant access localhost using my local ip(192.168.1.36). Only with this: http://localhost/

When i try to connect with my local ip, the error like this:192.168.1.36 refused connection.

Maybe this is about the problem.

So how can i solve this problem?

**EDİT:(NEW PROBLEM)**

*Problem is about java-php connection now.

My server connects to php for queries.Here is the code for connect to php page.I take error in line "PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());".
And the error says: Connection refused:connect

```
try{
            // open a connection to the site
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.35/userControls/singin.php");
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            // activate the output
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            //con.setDoInput(true);
            PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());
            // send your parameters to your site
            ps.print(URLEncoder.encode("uname","UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uname, "UTF-8"));
            ps.print(URLEncoder.encode("&pass=","UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "utf-8"));

            ps.close();
            BufferedReader cin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = cin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(":::::::Worked:::::::::   " + line);
            }
           }/* catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }*/ catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Eror:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

How can i solve this second problem?

Comment: It's normal for a connection to go into `TIME_WAIT` and to have several similar entries there, if you've been trying to perform the connection several times. Are you sure it's not connecting? Is there an exception?

Comment: Socket connection is working now but the ip is still problem.The error is: Connection Refused: connect,     I edited the question, added new problem to the end with codes.

Comment: Check your `ServerSocket` object. It doesn't look like you're giving it an IP, so it is likely listening on `localhost`

Comment: Yes, I changed "localhost" to "192.168.1.35" and it worked.Now there is a problem about connection between java-php.Could you help about this too?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP. What is the problem?

Comment: I added the Java codes that connect to php page in the end of my post.The problem seems like this line : "PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());" .  I don't know using PrintStream class very good.Maybe i did something wrong.In the php side, there is 2 variable that is got with post method. The error says: Connection Refused:connect